# Is there any command tools that could list all the bp nodes info like IP Port etc after the mainnet launching?

Tags: block-producer

When the main net works well, is there any command line tools for us the check or monitor all the bp nodes ?

Answer (score 2):

No, Not yet. I imagine something like this will be released in the next month or two.